# How to use google drive images?

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch some images from my google dive into my android application, using google drives URL, what would be good approach

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a [DriveId](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId) from when you inserted the image, you can then retrieve the file using Drive.DriveApi.getFile() - this returns you a DriveFile.

Once you have a DriveFile, you can get an InputStream to the contents of the file as a Bitmap using open() and code such as

```
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
    .setResultCallback(
      new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
          // Handle an error
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
        InputStream is = driveContents.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        // Do something with the bitmap

        // Don't forget to close the InputStream
        is.close();
      });
```